# Mysqli second query doesn't work

Tags: mysqli

I want to use de result from my first query to insert in a second query, there's not error in the sintaxis.

I've been reading a lot but anything seems to work.

HELP!!!!

```
$sql = "CALL sp_producto(1);";
    $rs = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $idNuevo;
    if ($fila = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
        $idNuevo = $fila['idNew']; //recupera el id del insertado
        $talleres = explode(",", $_POST["proceso_prod"]);
        foreach ($talleres as $t) {
            //THIS DOESN'T WORK BUT IDONT KNOW WHY
            $sql = "INSERT INTO proceso_produccion () VALUES (" . $idNuevo . ", ".$t.")";
            echo $sql;
            $mysqli->query($sql);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove `()` from `INSERT INTO proceso_produccion ()` and remove `;` from `CALL sp_producto(1);`

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO proceso_produccion () VALUES (" . $idNuevo . ", ".$t.")
```

This line is the issue, if you are inserting values in all of your table columns no need to have this `()`
,change your code to this :

`INSERT INTO proceso_produccion VALUES (" . $idNuevo . ", ".$t.")`

but if you are inserting to only certain column, you have to specify the column names,

like this :

`INSERT INTO proceso_produccion ('firstColumn','anotherColumn') VALUES (" . $idNuevo . ", ".$t.")`

Comment: thanks but that is not the problem.

The problem is that i cant't use the mysqli->real_query twice

Answer (score 0):

Niang answered right, but also check if both values you are entering are integers. Otherwise, the should be in quotes like so:

```
INSERT INTO proceso_produccion ('firstColumn','anotherColumn') VALUES ('" . $idNuevo . "', '".$t."')
```

Also, this condition is not a real condition:

```
if ($fila = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
```

You are only assigning value to $fila this way. It should be:

```
if ($fila == $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
```

Finally, if query still doesn't work can you please post echoed query, the result of echo $sql.

Comment: the first query works well, but the second doesn't, I've print on screen $sql and if I paste it in mysql it works fine, i don't know why but I can use mysq->real_query twice in the same code.

Comment: Well, it must work if you are sure that it works first time. The only possible reason that I can think of is that this whole block doesn't get executed. Are you sure that array $talleres is not empty?